To prepend / precede a text property with a hash mark, or not to prepend / precede a text property with a hash mark. That is the question
Continuing my LilyPond studying, I was learning about changing (pre-staff) instrument names when I found this (old) email which uses the following syntax:
\set Staff.instrumentName = #"Violin 1"

I also found this String quartet template which uses:
\set Staff.instrumentName = #"Violin 1 "

I also found this SE question which uses:
\new Staff \with { instrumentName = #"2 Oboes"}

And this snippet which uses:
\set Staff.instrumentName = #"2 Flauti  "

And this snippet which uses:
\set Staff.instrumentName = #"Trumpet 1"

Cool. So it's clear. I need to prefix or precede my "classic double-quote-enclosed strings" with a hash mark.
Then I read the "Learning Manual's "Modifying Modifying context properties" which says:

... and text is enclosed in double apostrophes.

and

A text property should be enclosed in double quotation signs, as above
...

Hmmm. No mention of the hash mark. And agreeing with the "hash mark not necessary" stance, I find the most recent version of the String quartet template which says:
\new Staff \with { instrumentName = "Violin 1" }

I dig through historical versions of the String quartet template and discover a change between versions v2.18 which used a hash mark:
\set Staff.instrumentName = #"Violin 1 "

and v2.19 which didn't use a hash mark:
\new Staff \with { instrumentName = "Violin 1" }

I check it myself:
\new Staff {
  \set Staff.instrumentName = "Aarrgghh!"
  r1
}

compiles and correctly sets the instrument name, so unless I am mistaken, the Learning Manual's "Modifying context properties" section which states:
\set ContextName.propertyName = #value


Note the occurrence of hash signs, (#), in two different places – as
part of the Boolean value before the t or f, and before value in the
\set statement.

is wrong. But by this point, my brain has melted. Can someone please explain to me, in a way that I can understand, when do I prefix / precede a text property with a hash mark, and when I do not prefix / precede a text property with a hash mark? TIA.

As someone not familiar with LilyPond, is this one of those things that has no impact on the rendered display, and is just a programming convention, like prepending the names of observables with $?

@AndyBonner Yes and no. It is basically resorting to the more powerful, less native syntax, which was necessary in the past, but is no longer necessary.

For this you need to understand what # actually means. Lilypond is a both a program and a language for encoding music. The program Lilypond does take the language, parses it and evaluates it and then typesets it into music. Now, this language is intended to describe music and can thus be limited, and the more complex it becomes, the harder parsing it will be. Take for example an input such as 8. What is this? Is this a number? Is this a duration?
The parser will need to guess how to interpret what it sees, and this ability needs work. Now, if that does not work we can use a trick. Lilypond actually uses a language called scheme (a LISP dialect) for a lot of stuff, and the data structures used by Lilypond are mostly scheme data structures or accessible via scheme interfaces. What this also means is that we can ask the Lilypond parser to instead of evaluating code as Lilypond code evaluating code directly as scheme code. To tell the parser to do so we use the symbol # (or the symbol $, which has a slightly different meaning).
So we can use # to evaluate complex expressions, but also to enter things we cannot enter otherwise. And as the parser evolves some situations where this would have been necessary are possible without. (A prominent example for this would be ##t and ##f — entering the scheme values #t and #f, as Lilypond does not have native truth values.)
I would guess that that previously the parser would have interpreted "..." as so called markup rather than a string. Now Lilypond is able to understand that a string can also be a markup, and so this works out fine.
Now, notating strings natively should workout fine with modern Lilypond, as well as most other cases (such as floats 3.4, negative numbers -3, ...). You see the need for # in some cases (not all) where you need a so called symbol (#'a-symbol), and of course if you want to specify more complex scheme expressions or references to scheme variables when \... does not work.

Ok, so if I understand you correctly, # means that the following token is scheme, not LP. And for a given fixed version of LP the program (and hence a given fixed version of LP the language), there may be (in a single .ly input file) position-dependent places where I would need to write "some string" and other position-dependent places where I would need to write #"some string". Or, in other words, depending on where the string is located, the parser may, or may not, be able to "add the hash-prefix" itself. Have I understood this correctly?

@jaimet More or less. The parser would not add the # token, but it will interpret the input as the correct things. # is kind of the more powerful but not native LP-code like thing that relies on Lilypond being able to evaluate Scheme expressions. And a lot of development went into having to rely on this as little a possible. For strings I don’t think these is any need to write #... anymore. But for other things there can still be the need. That is usually when one token can mean multiple things and it is not clear which one that would be.

So that would be "Ambiguous grammars" vs. "Unambiguous grammars", if my memory of "Principles of compiler design" (Aho & Ullman, 1977) serves me correctly. Ok, to summarize my current understanding then, hash-prefixing strings/text was "more necessary" in the past, is "now less necessary" than it was (due to improvements in the parser) and in fact may not be necessary at all anymore. I think I might send a confirmatory question to the lilypond-user mailing list. Fingers crossed and praying.
